# Velocity vector of a parametrized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]

In fig. 2.4, at the point of intersection of curve shouldn't we will be having two velocity vectors?
How to handle that?
Or we will be having only one velocity vector.If that is the case then why is it so?
Thanks

Comment: At that point in *space* there are two velocity vectors.  However they occur at different points in *time*.

Comment: Okie and can an integral curve be like this?(self intersecting). I think no as then we will have two values of vector field at same point.

Comment: If you add the time axis, then for any reasonable DE an integral curve cannot self-intersect (except at $t=\pm \infty$).

Comment: My reason is correct or there is something else behind it?

Comment: I would say it's because generally DEs represent *deterministic* processes.

Comment: Okie thanks a lot.

Comment: Okie is it so because at point of intersection we will have two velocity vectors but integral curve has the property that  at each point of curve velocity vector and value of vector field coincides.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here but you've gotten away from a discussion of whether a self-intersecting path in space will have multiple velocity vectors at the point of intersection.  So I'd suggest asking a new question specifically about the intersection of *integral curves* of whatver types of DEs you're considering.